# Loading PDF's to an iPad split view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad

I'm working on a split view application that is used to view PDF files in a webView.  Right now I am able to get three PDF's loaded to the app, and have their titles displayed in the table in the RootView.  I'm able to select them and have them displayed to the DetailView, however the sizing the of PDF isn't what I want it to be.

My hope is that the PDF will take up the whole screen and will resize itself to fit the screen if it is too large or too small.  One PDF I have is too large and I have to scroll left or right to view the sides of the file, another I have is too small, it isn't centered and instead pushed to the left side of the screen and the empty side on right is filled in with black.

How do I make it so that the PDF's size themselves correctly to fit the whole screen and have even margins on the sides?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of PDF questions on SO today. Sounds like you may have to abandon the webview and go to a tiledlayer CGPDFDocument route. Check out the answer I just posted at [Reading text and images from a pdf document in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732219/reading-text-and-images-from-a-pdf-document-in-ios)