# Reading text and images from a pdf document in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, uiwebview, catiledlayer

I'm displaying locally stored pdf in my iPad application. Here's the code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About Downloads" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[pdfWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Now, by default, you can't copy text or images from the PDF which is rendered by the UIWebView. Is there a way to let users copy text and/or images out of pdf?

I'm not familiar with CATitledLayer, so i'm just wondering if it can help in this case?

Comment: This changed as of iOS5, you can now select text in UIWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple answer to this. PDF's are nested dictionaries composed of more dictionaries & arrays. You'll have to dig into [CGPDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html). [Voyeur](https://github.com/below/PDF-Voyeur) is an excellent tool to use while digging around in PDF's. [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) is a good suggested starting point for rendering PDF's.

Answer (score 1):

To get at the text in a PDF Document, I use PDF Kitten (https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten).  It works quite well, but as the author notes, is incomplete and does not support all font types.