# Read PDF Files as Simple Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading text and images from a pdf document in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732219/reading-text-and-images-from-a-pdf-document-in-ios)

I am trying to access some .pdf files in my ios app and read the text inside them which i later display in a UITextView.
I was able to extract text from .txt files, .doc files as well as .rtf files using a UIWebView.
But not sure how to proceed with .pdf files.
Please if someone can help me out with this. I just dont want to display the pdf in a webview, rather i would like to have the text content inside it for further manipulations.

Comment: Sorry to ask this but how did you extract text from doc files using a uiwebview?

Comment: u will have to bridge the txt and .doc files in a webview and then using the UIWebViewDelegate method- webViewDidFinishLoading you can get the data of the files using:
    NSString *document = [webView     stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
    NSLog(@"%@",document);